# Porting from Visual Studio 2005 to 2008 or above

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, visual-studio-2005, atl

I have a project which is implemented with Visual Studio 2005. I need to compile it again but I dont have the Visual studio 2005 anymore. I just have access to VS 2008, 2010 and 2012. When I compile the code, I got some linker errors which many of them are the same. It is as follows:

```
Error   48  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int (__cdecl* ATL::g_pfnGetThreadACP)(void)" (?g_pfnGetThreadACP@ATL@@3P6AIXZEA)    FEMesh_noacis_AMD64.lib
```

I would be really appreciated if anyone can help me with fixing this linker erro?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the library it's asking for is indeed built with the same version of visual studio?

Comment: You are right... That library is compiled with VS 2005. I also do not have access to that library code and it is a inside company code and it is not found on internet :(

Comment: I didn't think the name mangling between VC2005 and VC2008 had been changed (or since!) so perhaps you're just missing the lib reference to the library in the linker settings? (I get this all the time by adding a lib to the Debug build, and then watching as Release build fails...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you would want to fix that by rebuilding missing code with a matching tool... however if it is the only issue standing between you and successful execution, you can try defining the missing symbol yourself to satisfy linker:

```
namespace ATL
{
    extern UINT (*g_pfnGetThreadACP)();

    UINT PrivateGetThreadACP()
    {
        CPINFOEX Information;
        ATLVERIFY(GetCPInfoEx(CP_THREAD_ACP, 0, &Information));
        return Information.CodePage;
    }

    UINT (*g_pfnGetThreadACP)() = PrivateGetThreadACP;
};
```